# How to install java1.4 in ubuntu18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, apt

I need to run an open source Java software, but after compiling the system prompts because of the enum problem, so you can use java1.4 to run. The system I am using is ubuntu18.04, how can I install java1.4 in this ubuntu.

Comment: You should be able to compile using `-source 1.4`, but more fundamentally, there almost certainly is an updated version.

Comment: I am a person who just learned java, so the most urgent thing I need to know now is how to install java1.4 in ubuntu18.04.

Comment: Why not fix the the source code so that it works on a newer version of Java? Java 1.4 is super-old and not supported anymore. Don't use it.

Comment: Java 1.4 is almost 17 years old with the public updates ending 10 years ago. If you're using something that doesn't work with newer versions of Java, then maybe you should be looking for a replacement.